Outdated client error while connecting to gcp bigtable using data boost profile with go
I am using go lang to connect to gcp bigtable. I am trying to use the data boost profile for this. I am using the latest version of go and Google cloud bigtable.
When I read rows from bigtable I get error like client needs to be updated.
When I check the ineligibility metrics in gcp console I see the error like outdated client.
I added the dependency as:
cloud.google.com/go/bigtable v1.33.0
go version is 1.23.3
My sample code is:
func main() {

projectID := "project-id"
instanceID := "instance-id"
tableID := "table-id"


ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigtable.NewClientWithConfig(ctx, 
projectID, instanceID, bigtable.ClientConfig{
 App profile: "data-boost-profile"
})

if err != nil {`enter code here`
    log.Fatalf("Failed to create Bigtable client: %v", err)
}


// Open the table.
table := client.Open(tableID)




err = table.ReadRows(ctx, bigtable.PrefixRange(""), func(row bigtable.Row) bool {
    log.Printf("Row key: %s", row.Key())
    for family, items := range row {
        log.Printf("Family: %s", family)
        for _, item := range items {
            log.Printf("  Column: %s, Value: %s, Timestamp: %d",
                item.Column, string(item.Value), item.Timestamp)
        }
    }
    return true // Continue reading rows.
})
 if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Failed to read rows: %v", err)
 }
}

Exact error I see in my console is below:
"rpc error: code=Unimplemented desc= Client does not support Data boost yet. Please update your client."
I am not sure if data boost is not yet supported for go lang.
I try to use go lang client library for connecting to gcp bigtable and read rows. I need to read rows using the data boost profile.

Please provide a minimal repro of your issue so that others may try to replicate the behavior. "I get error like" is unhelpful. Please describe (using commands) exactly what you did and the error that you received.

Data Boost is currently in preview and Go client is not yet supported.
